# jsReport not rendering custom font

Tags: jsreport

I've been rendering jsreport PDFs succesfully on my development machine. However, when running jsreport on the test server PhantomJS is falling back the use the default font. Any idea how to solve or troubleshoot?

I'm using Handlebars and PhantomJS. Dev machine spec: jsReport 1.0.7 on Node v4.4.5 on 64 bit Win10. Test server spec: jsReport 1.0.7 on Node vx.x.x on 64 bit Win2012 R2 Server

Steps to reproduce:

1)  Upload fonts to jsReport

[fonts uploaded to jsreport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lneqq.png)

When selected, jsReport suggests using it as below:
{#image MavenPro-Black @encoding=base64}

2)  Add the “Shortcut” to the data file

```
{
    "assets": {
   "MavenPro-Black": "{#image MavenPro-Black}",
   "MavenPro-Bold": "{#image MavenPro-Bold}",
   "MavenPro-Medium": "{#image MavenPro-Medium}",
   "MavenPro-Regular": "{#image MavenPro-Regular}",
   "jquery": "{#image jquery}"
 },
  ……
}
```

3)  Use the asset in the Report

```
<head>
   <script src="{{assets.jquery}}"></script>
   <style>
       /* Common Classes */        
       @font-face {
        font-family: 'Maven Pro';
        src: url({{assets.MavenPro_Regular}}) format('truetype');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it works on your local is because you have probably this font already installed. The reason why it cannot work on the server is because you have typo in your code:

You data includes property `MavenPro-Regular`, but in template you access it using `{{assets.MavenPro_Regular}}`. You just need to change `-` to `_` in your data and it should work.

**Working example**:
https://playground.jsreport.net/studio/workspace/SklZyycYg/9

**Hint 1**: Use `text` recipe and print the raw output to troubleshoot such problems. You would immediately see that the url of font is not filled.

**Hint 2**: You should consider using [jsreport assets](https://jsreport.net/learn/assets) feature to embed fonts rather than images extension. You can find demo how to use it with description [here](https://jsreport.net/blog/fonts-in-pdf).

**Edit**
Assets extension is part of the default installation and can be considered stable since version 1.3.0

Comment: Hi Jan, 1) Thanks for your quick response. 2) Awesome product dude. Everyone I show it to loves the rich feature set whilst maintaining a lightweight footprint. 3) That's a great pickup. As a work-around I've hard coded the Font and that worked fixing the typo in the process.   4) I did see the Assets plugin page, but couldn't quite work it out. Forgive my novice question, but I how do I install the plugin? If it's installed by default (I remember reading that somewhere) where do I find the upload button? I'm pretty sure I can work it out from there. I'll look out for typos :-)   Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm....  Tried:   npm install jsreport-assets, which is probably the way to go, but studio has become unresponsive...   Will try to troubleshoot again later....

Comment: Ok, upgraded to the latest, which has the Asset Extension installed by default....

Comment: I've add edit since which version is asset extension included and stable.